# AJAX Response Rails 4 Does Not Return In Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I've just started coding in Rails 4, so I may need very specific instruction. I'm using AJAX to take user input from a text field, modify it (for simplicity's sake I'm just adding " yay!" on the end of it), and return the response as a string to the text field.

I believe I am sending my AJAX request correctly, but something in my controller or view isn't modifying or displaying the result.

Here is my code:

View (solve.html.erb):

```
<head>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "solve";
            var params = "field1=" + document.getElementById("field1").value;

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("field1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?" + params, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<h1>Solve!</h1>
<p>Type it in, type it in.</p>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="field1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1+1">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Solve</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Routes (routes.rb):

```
resources :equations
#rest of my routes code
get 'solve' => 'equations#solve'
```

Controller (equations_controller.rb):

```
class EquationsController < ApplicationController
  def solve
     if request.post? 
        new_var = params[:field1]
        other_var = "#{new_var} yay!"
        return other_var
    end
  end
end
```

If you have any questions, I'll get right back to you. Thank you so much for your help! Anything is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have tagged jQuery however no jQUery code could be seen throughout the snippet

Comment: I apologize! Thank you for pointing out my mistake, and I'll be sure to double check in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a `GET` request but checking if the request is `POST` in your `EquationsController#solve` method.  Update controller code as follows:

```
class EquationsController < ApplicationController
  def solve
     if request.get?                   # Change to `request.get?`
        new_var = params[:field1]
        other_var = "#{new_var} yay!"
        return other_var
    end
  end
end
```

Then the second problem is, you should be writing the output instead of returning it from the controller.  As you are expecting `text/plain` mime type, you should render text instead:

```
class EquationsController < ApplicationController
  def solve
     if request.get? 
        new_var = params[:field1]
        other_var = "#{new_var} yay!"
        render plain: other_var         # Change to `render plain: other_var`
    end
  end
end
```

This however, is not the recommended way to handle AJAX requests/responses in Rails.  Please refer to: [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).  Also, please see [The response object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object) for details on the same.

Comment: I made both of your changes, but when I go to my /solve page it renders " yay!" text and the rest of the screen is blank. Exactly what part of your first link is the part that would help me accomplish what I'm trying to? Just unsure. Thank you so much!

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to go over the page referenced by the first link.  Please see section **2.2.7 Rendering Text** which explains how you can include a layout in [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Comment: For the issue with rendering just `yay!`, can you ensure that your `params` hash actually contains the key `:field1`.  You could check this in  your log file or inspect the hash for debugging purpose using `Rails.logger.debug { params }` after the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in myFunction()

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         document.getElementById("field1").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
```

I think this works

Comment: I've tried that before and tested it one more time for safe measure, but it just pulls all of the html for the page into the text field. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think the controller's action is rendering the default 'solve.html.erb' view. so you should return just the value you wish like

```
class EquationsController < ApplicationController
  def solve
     if request.post? 
        new_var = params[:field1]
        other_var = "#{new_var} yay!"
        render html: other_var
    end
  end
end
```

and in js

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         document.getElementById("field1").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
```